# Jump to ending quote of a string during code completion in PHPStorm

Tags: string, phpstorm, code-completion

When completing code inside quotes, for example, the value for charset attribute of the HTML `<meta>` tag, PHPStorm comes up with some suggestions. After I choose a suggestion by highlighting it in the pop up menu and hitting enter, the string is completed inside the quotes and the caret (cursor) is positioned between the last character and the closing quote of the string. I want it to be positioned *after* the closing quote, so that I can continue typing the remaining attributes. Am i missing something? Right now I need to use the right arrow key to manually position the caret to a point after the closing quote. It's annoying.

Comment: please vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6697

Comment: @lena Voted for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6984

Comment: I voted for 6984 too. Now that I've noticed this inconvenience it's driving me _crazy_.

Comment: After a while you will get used to this inconvenience, don't worry :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a perfect solution, but, to deal with this I've added a Keymapping that maps [ COMMAND + ENTER ] to "Move caret to Line End".

It's more natural for me than moving my hands out of position to get to the arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keymapping solution it works perfect for me, but instead of "Move caret to Line End" use "Right".

Answer (score 0):

In webstorm i just added the tab character as a keyboard binding to "right" and left the other default mappings in place as well. This is what my entry looks like now: 
[image]